# Objective-C - Invalid operands to Binary Expression ('double') to ('double *')

Tags: ios, objective-c, time

I am following along with a tutorial to learn iOS Game Development. In the video he has no error, so idk if there is a method missing or if I am doing something wrong. I am a CS Major in college and have had a class in Obj-C & I am currently in iOS7 app development class. I am encountering this Error...

**Invalid operands to Binary Expression ('CFTimeInterval' (aka'double') and 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *'))**

```
/* NSTimeInterval *_dt;
   NSTimeInterval *_lastUpdateTime;
*/

//The above shows what _dt and _lastUpdateTime are

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if(_lastUpdateTime)
    {
        _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime; //Line of Error From Title
    }

    else
    {
        _dt = 0;
    }

    _lastUpdateTime = &currentTime;
    [self movePipes];
}
```

Comment: Why are `_dt` and `_lastUpdateTime` declared as pointers? They shouldn't be.

Comment: If you're a CS major you should know the difference between a *double* and a pointer to a *double*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
NSTimeInterval *_dt;
NSTimeInterval *_lastUpdateTime;
```

to:

```
NSTimeInterval _dt;
NSTimeInterval _lastUpdateTime;
```

Then get rid of the `&` in the following line:

```
_lastUpdateTime = &currentTime;
```

`NSTimeInterval` is a primitive type, not a class type. You don't want the pointer.